# Fancy Ticks Foramt - Please give explanations for this part of code

Tags: python, matplotlib

Currently, I am studying on Matplolib. There is an example code from the Fancy Ticks Format parts that I hardly comprehend it. Here is what they are trying to do:

At first, they try to change the ticks of the graph.

> ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(np.pi / 2))
>   ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(np.pi / 4))

However, the ticks was shown in float which is not really nice. Then they try to change it into the notation of pi.

```
def format_func(value, tick_number):
    N=int(np.round(2*value / np.pi))
    if N == 0:
        return  "0"
    if N ==1:
        return r"$\pi/2$"
    .........
    else:
        return r"${0}\pi$".format(N//2)
```

> ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(format_func))

Please explain the `r"$\pi/2$"` and `r"${0}\pi$"`.

It reminds me about the Regular Expression but not for sure about it.

For your further information about the code of the book: (pg 281)

https://tanthiamhuat.files.wordpress.com/2018/04/pythondatasciencehandbook.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is taking advantage of `matplotlib`'s support for [LaTeX rendering](https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html).

In particular:

- it uses raw strings `r"..."` in order to avoid escapes being introduced into the string;
- the `$...$` portion is the LaTeX methodology for wrapping a formula.